# Install4J create Link in the dock

Tags: macos, install4j, dock

I want Install4J to create a link in the dock on macOS during installation process. How to do it? The link will point to localhost.

For windows I use an action called "Create a windows URL link". How do I add an Icon like this at MacOS?

Comment: is [this](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/12/24/add-website-shortcut-to-mac-dock/) what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you. It should be automatically performed by the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 10, this is not supported. I've added it to our issue tracker.